# Cmake Parse Error Expected a command name, got unquoted argument with text "//Path"

Tags: c++, plugins, makefile, cmake

I am trying to follow some old instructions on a past project for compiling and installing a Maya plugin and I have ran into an error on a Mac. The instruction says, in terminal, use the command `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" "/CMakeLists.txt path"`

There are no errors in finding the source files but I do get the error: /CMakeLists.txt:17:
Parse error.  Expected a command name, got unquoted argument with text "//Path".
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Here is the first part of the CMakeList.txt:

```
# This is the CMakeCache file.
# The syntax for the file is as follows:
# KEY:TYPE=VALUE
# KEY is the name of a variable in the cache.
# TYPE is a hint to GUI's for the type of VALUE, DO NOT EDIT TYPE!.
# VALUE is the current value for the KEY.

########################
# EXTERNAL cache entries
########################

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_AR:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/X11/ar

//Choose the type of build, options are: None(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or
// CMAKE_C_FLAGS used) Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel.
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING
```

If I delete line 17 (//Path to a program.) the error just moves to the next line and so on. I've tried searching for answers but I've come up with no luck. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What command *exactly* are you running? That sample `cmake` command seems like it is suggestion and not a literal path. It probably wants you to pass the path to the directory with that `CMakeLists.txt` file instead of that string (unless you are doing that already). Also that file seems to have two comment markers which seems strange. Try changing the `//` to `#` perhaps.

Comment: Your file is not a CMakeLists.txt, but a CMakeCache.txt (it even says so on the top) - these are two different things, with very different content and format. CMakeCache is generated from CMakeLists.txt after first `cmake` run. Are you sure the snippet you posted comes from CMakeLists.txt ?